# Clarification on question involving Strings and reading multiple strings

Tags: python

Can anyone possibly clarify what this question is asking or potentially give me an example. It seems very confusing to me.

UserString():  This   function   asks   the   user   to   input   m   strings.   As   the strings   are read, they should be concatenated into a single string st. After reading the m strings   and   forming   the   single   string   st,   it   should return the concatenated st to the main() function. This function has one parameter, an integer to receive m

Here is my code so far

```
def main():
    while True:
        number = input("Enter a positive number: ")
        try:
            val = int(number)
            if val < 0:
                print("Sorry, input must be a positive integer, try again")
                continue
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not an int!")
    print(number)

def userString():
    string = input("Enter number of strings you want to read: ")





main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the tour and take the time to read How to Ask and the other links found on that page. Invest some time with the Tutorial practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/tour
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Which part of the question you don't understand? How to ask for input? How to ask for input multiple times? How to concatenate strings? How to return value? How to set parameter for function? You need to be more specific.

Comment: So where's your function that takes one parameter `m`?  If you can't at least get that yourself, I don't think anybody can help you understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many different ways to do this in Python.

In general the approach will be something like:

- Read the input for M strings,
- collect input from the user in a for
  loop which loops M times and stores input in a collection
- after that
  iterate through the collection and add each entry to a new string and
  return that string

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be from a tutorial somewhere. I do **strongly** recommend you try and solve the question yourself - that's the best way to learn. Maybe try following @Fermi-4's ideas.

If you are *really stuck* and *really can't*, here's my solution to this question.

```
def main() -> None:
    try:
        m = int(input('How many strings:'))
        assert m > 0
        # Using assert as you can easily add other conditions below here & be caught by the AssertionError.
    except ValueError:
        print("[Error]: That's not an int")
        return
    except AssertionError:
        print('[Error]: Your input is invalid.')
        return
    
    valueFromUser = UserString(m)
    print(valueFromUser)
    
def UserString(m : int) -> str:
    concatenated = ''
    print('Please enter '+ str(m) + ' strings.')
    for line in range(m):
        concatenated += input(f'Input String #{str(line+1)}:')
    return concatenated

main()
```

A gentle reminder in case if you're a student & this is for your university homework/assessment/etc: Please don't copy the code. Plagiarism won't help with your study.